# Disambiguation similar behaving git commands checkout -- and restore

Tags: git

So for years I have been using a subset of git commands that served me well. But I need to know the difference and preferred use of two very similar behaving commands. So.

When I have edits in one or more files that are checked into the repository and I want to remove all those edits (edits have not been staged), I use the command:

`git checkout -- <path>`

But apparently there's a more modern alternative.

`git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree <path>`

Is `git checkout -- <path>` going to be deprecated at some point? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: The basic idea is that `git checkout` did too many things that were only related in ways that make sense to people who know all the internals of git. `git restore` and `git switch` together can do basically the same things, but separated them out into things that make sense when grouped together. Having said that: I've never stopped using `checkout`, so I can't be more precise than this ;-)

Comment: From my (brief) experience with the git community, they are very interested in keeping behavior of existing commands so i wouldn't expect checkout to behave differently from the way it does in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main difference in behavior between the two commands :

```
git restore --source={xxx} [--worktree] [--staged] -- <path>
# and
git checkout {xxx} -- <path>
```

is

- `git restore` will *delete* files that are not present in `{xxx}`,
- `git checkout` will not touch these.

So `git restore` has the desired behavior "restore that file/that directory to its exact state in commit `{xxx}`", with more room for accidental deletion.

Depending on the options you use ([`--worktree` and/or `--staged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#Documentation/git-restore.txt--W)), the deletion will happen on disk and/or in the index. There also is a [`--overlay`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#Documentation/git-restore.txt---overlay) option to prevent deletion (and basically behave like `git checkout {xxx} -- <path>`).

---

`git checkout` is so much part of git (so many scripts depend on its current behavior), it is IMHO extremely unlikely that it changes behavior in such a drastic way.